# stuck on Overview line at the time of drupal database update

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to up-grade my website 7.22 to 7.26 and i was follow all the steps which is defined in Drupal forum.
 The steps are:

Log in as a user with the permission "Administer software updates".

Go to Administration > Configuration > Development > Maintenance mode. Enable the "Put site into maintenance mode" checkbox and save the configuration.

Remove all old core files and directories, except for the 'sites' directory, the original install profile in the 'profiles' directory and any custom files you added elsewhere.

If you made modifications to files like .htaccess or robots.txt, you will need to re-apply them from your backup, after the new files are in place.

Sometimes an update includes changes to settings.php (this will be noted in the release announcement). If that's the case, replace your old settings.php with the new one, and copy the site-specific entries (especially the lines giving the database name, user, and password) from the old settings.php to the new settings.php.

Download the latest Drupal 7.x release from http://drupal.org/project/drupal to a directory outside of your web root. Extract the archive and copy the files into your Drupal directory.

Re-apply any modifications to files such as .htaccess or robots.txt.
Run update.php by visiting http://www.example.com/update.php (replace www.example.com with your domain name). This will update the core database tables.
If you are unable to access update.php do the following:

Open settings.php with a text editor.
Find the line that says:
$update_free_access = FALSE;
Change it into:
$update_free_access = TRUE;
.

But it is stuck on Overview line at the time of drupal database update.
I click continue and nothing moves forward. There are no errors or anything, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Please suggest me what can i do .

Thank you in advance.